# How to configure xterm cursor to be a perfect square?

Tags: fonts, cursor, xterm

Escape sequences can alter the symbol and color of the cursor in a terminal, but how can I change the aspect ratio? When using a square font (e.g. [Panoptica](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/shinn/panoptica/)), I would like that it prints with the same ratio, i.e. same width than height. Can the grid in a xterm be altered in such a way that whatever you print shows "squared"?

Update: Letters in a perfectly squared font (like Panoptica) will of course show squared, what I want to be square is **the box** that contains the letter, which keeps being rectangular; that's why I added the reference to the xterm's grid. May be I'm using the wrong terms.